# Convergence of a Sequence Proof (Introduction)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, proof-explanation

**Problem**: Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$. It converges to $0$. Proof that it converges to $0$

**Proof**: Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Let $N=\left \lceil \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} \right \rceil$. For $n>N$ we have that

$$ |\frac{1}{n^2}-0|$$
$$= \frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$<\frac{1}{N^2} $$
$$ \leq 1/(1/\sqrt{\epsilon})^2$$
$$=\epsilon$$

Q.E.D

**Questions**

- What is the sratchwork done to find such a $N$? (Normally I woudl see it by the calculations)
- Why use the ceiling function?

Answer (score 1):

Really we need to have $\frac{1}{n^2} \lt \varepsilon$. Solving it gives $n \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} $. And as we need natural solutions we take $N=\left \lceil \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} \right \rceil$. Now $n \gt N$ solve initial inequality.

Comment: oh! I think I just got it. So we solve for n in the inequality $|a_n - a|<\epsilon$ and then as we only need natural solutions we either take floor or ceiling. When do we know which to take in generel?

Comment: Depends on sequence formula. Generally it is not very easy, so we use some helpful tools: separate arithmetic operations, make variable substitution etc. Sometimes we are not able to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

When working with the $(\varepsilon,\delta)$ definition of a limit, a suitable $N$ can often be found by starting with

$$|a_n-L|<\varepsilon$$

and manipulating the inequality until you end up with a statement of the form $n>K$. $a_n=1/n^2$ is no exception.

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{n^2}-0\right|<\varepsilon &\iff \frac{1}{n^2}<\varepsilon\\
&\iff n^2>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\\
&\iff n>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}
\end{align*}

Thus, a suitable $N$ is given by $\left\lceil\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\right\rceil$. Why the need for the ceiling brackets? Well, the $(\varepsilon,\delta)$ definition spelled out for limits of sequences explicitly requires that the lower bound on $n$ be a non-negative integer, and $1/\sqrt{\varepsilon}$ isn't always an integer.

**Note**: you don't actually need to choose $N=\left\lceil\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\right\rceil$ to complete the proof; any $N$ that is at least $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$ will do the trick.

Comment: oh! I think I just got it. So we solve for n in the inequality $|a_n - a|<\epsilon$ and then as we only need natural solutions we either take floor or ceiling. When do we know which to take in generel?

Comment: @mathstudent23 in general, you'll use the ceiling of the lower bound. This is because $\left\lceil x\right\rceil\geq x$, so taking $N$ to be $\lceil\text{*lower bound*}\rceil$ ensures that $n>N\geq\text{*lower bound*}$. In contrast, $\lfloor x\rfloor\leq x$, so taking $N=\lfloor\text{*lower bound*}\rfloor$ will not guarantee that $n>\text{*lower bound*}$.

Comment: I see! regarding the proof itself. I do not really find the write up given in "my proof" that good. Would we just be able to reverse the equation that you have written and thus complete the proof? Would seem more elegant.

Comment: @mathstudent23 if you were dealing with the limit of a real function, then yes. Here, we're dealing with a sequence, so (strictly speaking) you do need to declare what $N$ you chose before presenting your sequence of steps and/or logical implications. Also, your write up is fine.